# Request Timeout (H-12) on POST requests

Tags: heroku, timeout

We're facing an interesting problem on our staging server on Heroku. Each post/put/delete request freezes for about 10 secondes or more and some of them eventually time out resulting in a Heroku H-12 time out error. 
Another interesting detail: the request seems to be processed after the time out because the database records get updated. We do not process a big data, we're just trying to update one field on one record in the DB.
Our local environment (localhost:3000) is working properly. We do not have any blocking action (sending email, processing big queries, ...)
We've tried activating/deactivating caching (dalli), asset compilation, we've switched the instance of our staging server. We've tried different settings in our staging.rb.

Any suggestions on how we could try to troubleshoot this?

```
2012-10-08T21:32:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/users/151" for 67.180.34.143 at 2012-10-08 21:32:15 +0000
2012-10-08T21:32:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
2012-10-08T21:32:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n4xK0Esi2zgBqSRtDTu3IEhnUAv0//bAkjLnKyk7xFk=", "user"=>{"role"=>"2", "designer_status"=>"1", "invitation_limit"=>"56"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"151"}
2012-10-08T21:32:45+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> POST ziba-exygy-2.herokuapp.com/users/151 dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://ziba-exygy-2.herokuapp.com/users
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 30304ms (ActiveRecord: 53.7ms)
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /users/151] invalidate, pass
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (3.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 42 LIMIT 1
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (12.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 151 LIMIT 1
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.8ms)  BEGIN
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (3.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'pierre+tttttttttt@blablabla.com' AND `users`.`id` != 151) LIMIT 1
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:    (3.1ms)  COMMIT
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.7ms)  BEGIN
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'pierre+tttttttttt@ blablabla.com' AND `users`.`id` != 151) LIMIT 1
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:    (11.6ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `invitation_limit` = 56, `updated_at` = '2012-10-08 21:32:31' WHERE `users`.`id` = 151
2012-10-08T21:32:46+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.9ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: This looks like a candidate for serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that our staging server didn't include all the Heroku add-ons the live server has. 
One of the add-on missing was Flying Sphinx. Some of our models assume Sphinx was there and would try to use it causing that behavior.